UniswapV3.slot0() costs too much gas
Have a simple method in my solidity contract with just one method were I am testing to get a UniswapV3Pool value for a token and just through testing the method on BinanceSmartChain-Testnet the method always returns:

The method is just:
/// @notice
///    calculates USD token price from main UniswapV3Pool
function calculatePriceInStableCoinV2
(
  address _adrUsdtPool
)
public view
returns
(
  uint160
)
{
  (uint160 sqrtPriceX96, , , , , , ) = IUniswapV3Pool(_adrUsdtPool).slot0();
  return sqrtPriceX96;
}

I don't know, but I have tried it many times and the method just fails to execute, is this an issue with the .slot0() method in the UniswapV3Pool contract ?

What is the value of your _adrUsdtPool? Looks like it's an address that doesn't implement the slot0() function.

@PetrHejda The _adrUsdtPool is a valid V3Pool I created on last night and was passing to the function as an argument.
Anyway, I came back to the issue in the morning and it just started working out of nowhere, perhaps some issue on the BSC-Testnet. Thank you for the help.

All working as expected after a delay in the BSC-Testnet.
